# Inserting Documents into MongoDB and ignore the duplicate documents

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to insert documents into MongoDB but I want to have only unique documents and whenever encounter a duplicate document, just ignore it if it is already exists and go to the next one. I am using the following code but apparently it does not work.

```
var keys = IndexKeys.Ascending("TrackingNumber");
var options = IndexOptions.SetUnique(true).SetDropDups(true);
_collection.CreateIndex(keys, options);`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to *ignore* these, it's probably best to do it in code, though that might not be that easy in a multi-client environment.

The `dropDups` flag is a parameter of the index *creation* only, so it will drop duplicates it finds while creating the index. The flag will be ignored for inserts afterwards, because it's not even a parameter of the index.

A better way, though not exactly the behavior you're looking for, is to use [upserts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior), i.e. operations that insert a document if not yet present and update it if the document that was searched existed before. That has the advantage of being an idempotent operation (which the ignore strategy is not).

Comment: But c# does not support upsert.Does it?

Comment: Of course it does. The C# driver supports all MongoDB features. There's even a helper method, Save(), see http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#save-tdocument-method

Comment: I am reading a CSV file and parse it tp Bson document. In my case, how can I use upsert?

Comment: Why are you reading from csv to BSON? Why not just use a class? You can still use the upsert with `BsonDocument`.

Comment: I need to parse a CSV file and insert some columns into MongoDB